# Aptana Studio3 java error on launc

Tags: installation, aptana

I am new to Aptana.
I would like it to try it but I am having some issues and I didn't find answer on official docs.

I'm using windows 7 with JRE 7 (and NO! for many reason I cannot change this version).
I was able to install Aptana Studio3, but when I started i receive the windows error msg:
Java Virtual Machine Launcher
Error: could not open 'C:Java\jre7\lib\i386\jvm.cfg'

And... under 
C:\Java\jre7\lib\
 I don't have any i386 library

Any idea to how to solve this?
Thank you
G.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing AptanaStudio3.ini
Add -vm argument like this:

**-vm
*YOUR-JDK-HOME*/bin/javaw.exe**

Comment: Thank you for your answer Martin. Unfortunately (or Fortunately) I already moved to Sublime Text.